# curious behaviour of scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I realise this code is faulty. 
However, I came across some curious behaviour which I was wondering if somebody could explain.

Example 1 :

```
   char *foo;
   scanf("%s",foo);
   printf("%s",foo);
```

Output is : **(null)**.

Example 2 :

```
  int i;
  char *foo;
  scanf("%s",foo);
  printf("%s",foo);
```

Output is : **val of foo** !

Why would the presence of *int i* cause this to "work"?

Comment: It doesn't work. It happens to seem to do what you expect it to, but it's undefined behaviour and therefore a serious bug.

Comment: From what you posted, foo has no value.   It is a pointer to an unassigned piece of memory.

Comment: I guess it would be quite annoying found this kind of bug in your own programs. ;)

Comment: Even if you do figure out how it's "supposed" to work, using `%s` with `scanf` is totally insecure and there is no legitimate use of it.  You don't know how big the buffer needs to be.  There is no way to know.  This will always be a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`foo` is a pointer, but you haven't set it to point at any memory that you've allocated, so instead it just has a random value at startup, and hence is pointing at some random section of memory.  Hence, anything could happen (i.e. *undefined behaviour*).

The presence of `int i` just changes the position of `foo` on the stack, and hence the particular random value that it has.  You shouldn't read anything meaningful into this differing behaviour, as it's still undefined.